# Issues with sfDoctrinePager pagination

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, pagination

I am using sfDoctrinePager in my module. I search the table on one or more criteria. First time the result displayed is correct but after it if I click on page 2 or more it again gives me the whole resultset and my search resultset is lost.

I am facing this issue for the first time, even though I have been using sfDoctrinePager since a long time.

I get this Array from my search form

```
(
    [field_type] => log_type
    [field_value] => ABC
    [is_active] => on
)
```

I send this array variable to my model:

```
$getQuery = $objMgr->getSearchQuery($request->getPostParameters());
```

** The query which runs in model is:

```
public function getSearchQuery($arrSearchValues)
{
  $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
          ->select('u.*')
          ->from('SomsConfigValues u');
          ->where('u.deleted_at IS NULL');

  if(isset($arrSearchValues['is_active']) && $arrSearchValues['is_active'] == 'on'){
    $q->where('u.is_active = ?', 1);
  }      
  if(isset($arrSearchValues['field_type']) && $arrSearchValues['field_type'] != ""){
    $revertChg = ucwords(str_replace("_", " ", $arrSearchValues['field_type']));
    $q->andWhere('u.field_type = ?', $revertChg);
  }
  if(isset($arrSearchValues['field_value']) && $arrSearchValues['field_value'] != ''){
    $q->andWhere('u.field_type = ?', $arrSearchValues['field_value']);
  }
  return $q;
}
```

First time I get the perfect searched result, but second time (when I click on page 2 it gives me whole resultset).

My action is:

```
public function executeIndex(sfWebRequest $request)
{
$objMgr = AdminFactory::adminObject();
$getQuerys = $objMgr->getSearchQuery($request->getPostParameters());

$this->config_values = $getQuerys;     
$this->pager = new sfDoctrinePager('configValues',     sfConfig::get('app_max_row_display'));    
$this->pager->setQuery($this->config_values);
$this->pager->setPage($request->getParameter('page', 1));
$this->pager->init();
}
```

The template where I am using this pagination is:

```
<div class="grid_footer">
        <div style="padding:5px;">
          <?php if(count($pager->getLinks())) : ?>
          <div class="tableControl">
            <div class="pagination_inner">
              <?php if(!$pager->isFirstPage()){ ?>
                <?php echo link_to1(image_tag('/images/first.png'), 'configValues/index?page='.$pager->getFirstPage()) ?>
                <?php echo link_to1(image_tag('/images/previous.png'), 'configValues/index?page='.$pager->getPreviousPage()) ?>
              <?php } ?>
              <div class="numbers">
                <?php if ($pager->haveToPaginate()): ?>
                  <?php $links = $pager->getLinks(); foreach ($links as $page): ?>
                    <?php echo ($page == $pager->getPage()) ? $page : link_to($page, 'configValues/index?page='.$page) ?>
                  <?php endforeach ?>
                <?php endif ?>
              </div>
              <?php if(!$pager->isLastPage()){    ?>
                <?php echo link_to1(image_tag('/images/next.png'), 'configValues/index?page='.$pager->getNextPage()) ?>
                <?php echo link_to1(image_tag('/images/last.png'), 'configValues/index?page='.$pager->getLastPage()) ?>
              <?php  } ?>
            </div>
          </div>
          <?php echo $pager->getNbResults() ?> results (page <?php echo $pager->getPage(); ?>/<?php echo count($pager->getLinks()); ?>)
          <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Can you show your action and also your view that shows where you create the `next page` links ...

Comment: I have added my action code and the template pagination code as well.

Comment: I think I have to store the query in the session to be retrieved again and again. This is the only way it seems it will work now.... Any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I was having exactly the same problem.  The only way around this I found is as you said, to store the query.  Instead of using the session, create an attribute in the user to store this.

in the action class put something like...

```
$this->getUser()->setAttribute('searchQuery', $getQuery);
```

This value persists through the session, so you can retreive it using e.g.

```
$storedQuery = $this->getUser()->getAttribute('searchQuery');
```

You can view the User attributes via the config item on the dev toolbar.